# String transformation in optimal time

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm

Having a word , í want it to trasnform in such way:

Miracle => Iraclemend.

Basicly take first letter append it to the end and then add end.

However the special characters has to stay at the same place from the end of the word so

```
   Britne's => Ritnesben'd
```

' is 2 position from end so it has to be in transformed string 2nd position from end, this also apply to UpperCase ( but from the start of the string ) so

```
 McBeth  => CbEthmend
```

My solution is as following:

1) Loop through the word and detect UpperCase and special character , 
   if its UpperCase , push index of the character into array of UpperCases it 
   its special character push character and index into array of specialchars ,
   and if its nothing above just append character to string ( if its UpperCase append its lowercase variant)

So Britne's will become britnes after first step. With index 2 and char "'"( from the end of the word ) in specialchars arr

2) Transform string so britnes will become ritnesbend

3) loop from 0 to the length of the word , every iteration check if that index match index from array of specialchars or upperCases. It if matches special chars add special char + next char , if it matches upperCases add uppercase version of character.

This runs in `O(2k) = O(k)` where k = length of the word.

Not having much experience with string transformation alghoritms , is there any faster solution?

pseudo code

```
 function detetectChars ( word , object )
    for i... word.length
      if  word[i] is spececial 
        object.specials.add( char: word[i] , index:i )
      if  word[i] is upperCase
        object.upper.add(i)

  function addSpecials ( word , object )
     upperIndex = 0;
     specialIndex = 0;
     transformed = "";
     for i... word.length
       if i == object.upper[ upperIndex ] 
         transformed += word[i].toUpper(); upperIndex++;
       if i == object.special[ specialIndex ]
         transformed += object.special[ specialIndex++ ] + word[i]
       else
          transformed += word[i]
    return transformed
```

Thanks for advices.

Comment: my bad typo , thanks for pointing out

Comment: "The solution should be implemented in javascript or c++" - pick **one**, or just omit both in favour of an optional [tag:pseudocode], given that there's no code in this question.

Comment: Doing better than O(k) would mean you manage to avoid needing to even look at every character. It's very easy to see that's impossible, given that you, at the very least, need to examine every character to see if it's a special character. You can also never go faster than O(output size) unless the majority of the characters from the input don't need to change or move, which is not the case here unless you represent strings as circular buffers.

Comment: @Dukeling added pseudocode

Comment: @Dukeling would you mind to elaborate on circular buffer?

Comment: What better solution is than having O(k), k being the length? O(2k), O(k) same thing unless you're after micro optimization

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi The better solution isnt neccesery faster , it can be smarter or less memory consuming

Comment: A [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) can be represented as fixed-size array with a start index and end index, with wrap-around. If you represent strings this way (which no language I know of does), you can move the first character to the end and add "end" in constant time (if the array is big enough), but this doesn't work if there are special characters or capitalisation in the middle of the string, which you still can't get around needing to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dispense with the extra arrays. Note the string's length and build the result one character at a time. Store the the first character (which is to come towards the end). As you traverse the string, if the previous character was uppercase or special, add the appropriate character to the accumulating solution at the appropriate offset.

You may want to also clarify when the uppercase and special characters' final positions are counted from the end or the beginning. For example, at present, it seems we could have various interpretations of "Si'ng":

```
Traversing from the end:
  ingSe'nd

Traversing from the start:
  In'gsend
```